# Linux iptables rejected - How do I enable it back?

Tags: iptables, forwarding

so I'm having a client in my network connected to the router through my computer with arpspoof. When I know want to stop the packet forwarding I execute:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

that is working how I expected. But when I try to do something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

I cannot manage to make the packets go through like in the beginning.

Am I doing something wrong or are there any other arguments I should use different from "ACCEPT"?

Comment: By the way you're using `-A`, maybe you want to use `-P` to set the **P**olicy (default action when no other rule in the chain applies). For example, `iptables -P FORWARD DROP` (can't be `REJECT`).

Comment: What does "the question should demonstrate reasonable system management skills" means? :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

IPtables has a list of rules, and for each packet, it checks the list of rules in order.  Once a rule is found that matches the packet and specifies a policy (ACCEPT, REJECT, DROP), the fate of the matching packet is determined; no more rules are examined.

This means that the order in which you run commands is important. When you use `iptables -A`, you add a rule to the end of the list of rules, so you will end up with a rule list that looks like this:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Since the `REJECT` rule comes **before** the `ACCEPT` rule, it gets triggered first, and thus forwarding won't happen.

You will therefore need to delete the `REJECT`rule instead of adding an `ACCEPT` rule. To delete the REJECT rule, run

```
iptables -D FORWARD -j REJECT
```

For more information, read the iptables manpage.

Answer (score 18):

The `-A` flag tells iptables to append the rule to the chain, meaning it ends up under your `REJECT` rule, and since the first rule matches, it's never used.

You list your rules with `iptables -L FORWARD` and you will see this yourself. To get rid of the rule you added, run

```
iptables -D FORWARD -j REJECT
```

Until there are no more such rules in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

What about to plase in the end of `FORWARD` rule for jump into new chain in which will be only one rule. It may be `ACCEPT` or `REJECT`. Say...

```
iptables -N accept-chain
iptables -A accept-chain -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j accept-chain
```

After that, you can change this one rule in `accept-chain` something like

```
iptables -R accept-chain 1 -j REJECT
```

to disable trafic or `-j ACCEPT` to enable.

Also what abount to turn on and off routing by

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

for disable packet forwarding and `"1"` - for enable.

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. This will insert your rule at the top instead of appending.

`iptables -I FORWARD 1 -j ACCEPT`

-I is to insert and #1 is the position